# Use of undeclared identifier 'cell'

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, cocoa-touch

i'm using a custom tablecell but i have a problem with parsing JSON in my uilabel i'm using the code below, this works great. To put something in my UILabel i simple do

```
cell.One.text = @"xx";
```

/

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier ";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) { 
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell"
                                                     owner:self options:nil];
        for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
            cell = (CustomCell *)oneObject;
    } 

    return cell;    

}
```

But when i try to parse something i normally do

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {


    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                         options:kNilOptions 
                                                           error:&error];
    NSArray* lastgame = [json objectForKey:@"items"]; 

    NSDictionary* game = [lastgame objectAtIndex:0];

    cell.One.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                         [strijd objectForKey:@"One"]
                         ];
}
```

But on this line i'm recieving an error: (Use of undeclared identifier 'cell') does anyone now how to fix thix?

```
cell.One.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                             [strijd objectForKey:@"One"]
                             ];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.One.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                         [strijd objectForKey:@"One"]
                         ];
```

your cell isn't declared in this methode, you have to do this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

after you declare your cell with: `CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];`

Comment: Don't get this, when i do an NSlog it's displaying the correct name but it's not displaying it in the  uilabel

Comment: no problem with your parser here! your variable 'cell' is not declared in this method, so your compiler don't know where to put the parsed string.

Comment: Ah how i can declare 'cell' in `- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {` need it there because an selector is sending data to fetchedDate

Comment: i would save your parsed values in a NSArray and then use [tableView reloadData] - this causes cellForRowAtIndexPath: to fire, where cell is declared and then set your Labeltext with the values of the NSArray